# google cloud pubsublite client on a serverless service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

First of all, I wanted to tag this post to google-cloud-pubsub-lite, but it's not created yet, my apologizes

I'm trying to get introduced with pubsub lite. I think it can be used as a "cheap" way to get an event store in a GCP project.

We usually create GAE standard services so we pay for what we used and at the same time it offers a great scalability.

Reading samples about how to currently subscribe to pubsub lite I observe that there's no option to supply an endpoint to receive new messages. The client connects to a subscription and stays awaiting for new messages to be streamed throw the connection.

I'm wondering a few qustions:

- Can we receive messages from a pubsub lite topic in a Cloud Function or in an endpoint of a GAE standard service?
- How can we scale to several clients for a topic subscription

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PubSub lite subscription supports only the Pull mode. So, you need to create one or several clients, to  plug them to the subscription and to get the messages.

In serverless mode, you should use the Push subscription more suitable for scalability and integration. In the pull subscription mode, you need to perform microbatches

- Create a Cloud Scheduler

  - `* * * * *` as frequency
  - Call the serverless tool that you want (Cloud Run, Cloud Function, App Engine)
- On the serverless product, when you receive a request, create a connection to the PubSub lite subscription and start to pull the messages.

  - If the pulling takes more than 1 minutes a new request will be received from Cloud Scheduler

    - Cloud Function will create a new instance automatically and start the pulling
    - Cloud Run can handle up to 80 requests concurrently. I recommend you to set the Concurrency paramater to 1 to have the exact same behavior as Cloud Function
    - *You can't play with the concurrency on App Engine*
    - Set the timeout to the max
  - If there is no new message (for example during 500ms) exit gracefully.
  - If the service timeout is close (15s before for example), stop the pulling and exit gracefully.

Like this, you could have several client to the same subscription (scale + 1 per minutes
and per scheduler, if the previous run is still active)

This workaround keep the serverless mode. If there is no messages, the pulling stopped after 500ms, or when there is no new messages. You scale up with your traffic.

---

However, I don't understand your concept of cheap event store.

- PubSub lite is not a pay as you go model, but a flat model. You reserve capacity and you pay for it 24/7 even if it is not used
- PubSub lite is zonal, and dangerous for HA
- You can keep the event up to the partition is full. But will not be cheaper to store the event elsewhere? BigQuery? Firestore? Cloud SQL?

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborated response. About pricing, documentation says that pubsub lite is an order of magnitude cheaper than PubSub. I don't understand what do you mean art "dangerous for HA"

Comment: Look at [this table](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/choosing-pubsub-or-lite#comparison_table). Don't hesitate if you have question on it!

Comment: Thanks again, I think I'll stay with regula PubSub. Any advice about choosing an store for the events? I guess that for event sourcing, If I finally decide to use this pattern, Firestore o Cloud SQL will be a better option.

Comment: All depends on how you will use the event and the number of event that you expect. Firestore is great, and serverless, but have limited capacity to query (only simple query are allowed). Cloud SQL (and BigQuery) allows you to create complex queries, why john, multiple "where" conditions,...